# Looking for zip codes and elevation of high schools

Tags: data-request, data.gov, geospatial, education

I'm researching United State zip codes and elevation. Specifically high schools elevations in US.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the US Department of Education's list of all public/private schools here:

http://nces.ed.gov/ccd/elsi/

This data contains the type of school (e.g., High School) along with the latitude and longitude coordinates.

There are a number of services on the Internet that offer elevation data based on coordinates. I have not used any, so I can't make a recommendation. I would google something like 'elevation by coordinates'